# undefined when creating table on phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, create-table

I have created about 50 fileds in this (keluarga) table in phpmyadmin. But when I submit to create this table, it's shown the warning "undefined". Anyone has the solution?

[image]

Comment: Can you check no any space in database name or any table name or feild name?

Comment: Scroll to the top of the page and work your way back down again check if anything is undefined.

Comment: i have checked the whole of fileds.

Comment: Then I suggest you forget about the wizard and create using the editor.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? Given what I can see in your screenshot, I'm able to create the table successfully with what you're showing (although the only difference I see is that I'm using the English translation). If you're able to come up with a reduced example of what causes the problem then perhaps we can help a bit more. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fcbead is the SQL generated when I used what's shown in your screenshot. phpMyAdmin doesn't do a great job of showing errors here, but usually moves the cursor to the offending field, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the datatype of the updated_by column. There is a varchar. You should change it to date related datatype.

Comment: This should be a comment, AND even if updated_by should be a date (and how would you know that) phpmyadmin will not consider it an error if defined as varchar

Comment: updated_by related someone who update the data. so i set varchar

Comment: you said updated_by related someone means there should be  some name or somting

Comment: then change the column name otherwise PHPMyAdmin can;t accept it with varcar